# Stop connecting Visual studio and django

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I am just beginner of django. If I type django-amin.py then visual studio pops up and stop. 
[image: type on anaconda]
[image: visual studio pops up]

I think it's because .py extension is connected with visual studio but
I can not change it to another.
How can I stop this stupid things?

[image: .py extension would open with visual studio]

-.py extension would open with visual studio
[image: can't change it to another program]
- can't change it to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, it happened because they do not find proper path to django-admin.py file.

so I changed the command to

```
python C:\Anaconda\Scripts\django-admin.py
```